# Is there any Linux command that I can use to show all the network interfaces except ifconfig

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel

I have to set up a network connection on a Arch Linux install (in Virtualbox) and I need to know what network interfaces I’m using. How can I do this without using `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 5):

The `ifconfig` tool (from `net-tools`) is being deprecated in favour of the `ip` tool, which is part of the `iproute2` suite.

This will list interfaces, and their ip addresses if they have one:

```
ip addr
```

Comment: Note that the answer from Palaeologus shows the `ip a` command - this is a valid abbreviation of `ip addr` which is the form you'll see in the help for `ip`.  In fact, any abbreviation of `address` will give the same result.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux.com website has the [following article](https://www.linux.com/learn/replacing-ifconfig-ip) on replacing the **ifconfig** command with **ip**:

> The first thing most people learn with the ifconfig command is how to
> find out what IP address has been assigned to an interface. This is
> usually done with the command ifconfig and no flags or arguments. To
> do the same with the ip command, it is run as such:
>
> **ip a**
>
> This command will list all interfaces with their associated
> information (Figure 1 above).
>
> Let’s say you only want to see IPv4 information (for clarity). To do
> this, issue the command:
>
> **ip -4 a**
>
> Or, if you only want to see IPv6 information:
>
> **ip -6 a**
>
> What if you only want to see information regarding a specific
> interface? You can list information for a wireless connection with the
> command:
>
> **ip a show wlan0**
>
> You can even get more specific with this command. If > you only want to view IPv4 on the wlan0 interface, issue the command:
>
> **ip -4 a show wlan0**
>
> You can even list only the running interface using:
>
> **ip link ls up**

Answer (score 1):

There's another option: use the kernel-provided directories (sysfs).

`ls /sys/class/net/`

That way it is easy to write:

```
for interface in $(ls /sys/class/net/) ; do
   echo $interface
   # ...
done
```

Note that the subdirectories can offer some info about the link level aspects (like the Ethernet MAC address), but not things like IP address.

In case someone wants to know what can be found there, here is the documentation:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net

Answer (score 0):

You can also the cli for Network Manager GUI, with the command to list the interfaces available, their type, connection state, and general connection "name"

`nmcli dev status`

Or you can go further with

`nmcli dev show`

Which will produce a result similar to Window's `ipconfig /all` command:

> acejavelin@BlazingIcicle ~ $ nmcli dev show
>   GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
>   GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
>   GENERAL.HWADDR:                         F8:32:E4:BD:00:00
>   GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
>   GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
>   GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
>   GENERAL.CON-PATH:                   /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
>   WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
>   IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.188/24
>   IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
>   IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
>   IP4.DNS[1]:                             208.67.220.220
>   IP4.DNS[2]:                             208.67.222.222
>   IP4.DNS[3]:                             192.168.1.1
>   IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::36f1:930b:48a:ab0e/64
>   IP6.GATEWAY:
>
> GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
>   GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
>   GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
>   GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
>   GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
>   GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
>   GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
>   IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
>   IP4.GATEWAY:
>   IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
>   IP6.GATEWAY:
>   acejavelin@BlazingIcicle ~ $

This could also be further refined for the specific interface

`nmcli dev show eth0` or `nmcli dev show wl0`

I have also found it useful to use an alias of `ipconfig` to actually be `nmcli dev show` on several computers I use.